# Why am i getting parsing errors in react-intl V3.2.2?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I updated my app from reactinlt 2.x to 3.2.2. Now I get the following error for each formatted message:

index.js:1437 [React Intl] Error formatting message: "titleBar.login" for locale: "de", using default message as fallback.
TypeError: A message must be provided as a String or AST.

Same for the default message:
Error formatting the default message for: "titleBar.login"
TypeError: A message must be provided as a String or AST.

And finally:
[React Intl] Cannot format message: "titleBar.login", using message source as fallback

However the GUI renders correctly and shows the German translation ("de"). But I get swamped in the Chrome console with error messages. What's wrong?

```
  const userInfo = useContext(UserContext);  // using hooks

  return (
    <UncontrolledDropdown className={styles.user}>
      <DropdownToggle>
        ...
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
       ...

        {!userInfo.isLoggedIn && (
          <DropdownItem>
            <div onClick={() => userInfo.login()}>
              <FormattedMessage {...msgs.login} />  // this has id=titleBar.login
            </div>
          </DropdownItem>
        )}
      </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );
};
```

Any idea how I can get rid of those error messages?

BTW: The error is thrown in format message. The message is parsed as a string (no placeholders etc). Then it checks if the AST is an array and throws because it is only one node...
Here's the code section:

```
 if (typeof message === 'string') {
      this.message = message;

      if (!IntlMessageFormat.__parse) {
        throw new TypeError('IntlMessageFormat.__parse must be set to process `message` of type `string`');
      } // Parse string messages into an AST.


      this.ast = IntlMessageFormat.__parse(message);
    } else {
      this.ast = message;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(this.ast)) {
      throw new TypeError('A message must be provided as a String or AST.');
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue - I'm having the same problem after upgrading from v2?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your translations file. It seems that the value of `titleBar.login` is not a string, but an object

Comment: Unfortunately not. It’s a string and it worked in version 2.x....

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it was a version mismatch between the client and server tooling. Meanwhile we updated to the latest version of all libs and ist working again.